# javascript, redirecting within a canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas

I am quite new to javascript and web programming in general. But basically, I have made a facebook canvas applicaiton and I was wondering how I can redirect to a page and make it stay within the iframe using javascript. For example: Right now i have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.parent.location = "http://www.google.com";
  </script>
```

but this redirects to the google page not inside the canvas application... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Google doesn't allow itself to be contained within an `<iframe>` ([`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)). Try another URL.

Comment: amazon.com? yahoo.com? anywebsite doesnt work for this i believe

Comment: Also, try `window.location` vs. `window.parent.location`.

Comment: Thanks the window.location works!

Answer (score 0):

In facebook the redirect option is disabled.So you cannot redirect to any uri unless it is clicked by user.
The redirect is an automatic and by clicking is manual.

```
11. The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site.


2.You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.
```

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/